# how to target a class in specific pages in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I know that .postid-81 would target a specific post page in wordpress, but what if i want to target more ids at once
this is my code but it's not working

```
 .postid-81, .postid-99  .featured-img .caption {
 display:none !important;
 }
```

edit: i want to do like this exactly

```
 .postid-81 .featured-img .caption, .postid-99 .featured-img .caption{
display:none !important;
}
```

but since i want to target like more than 8 pages, is there a way to minimize the code, and to not repeat .featured-img .caption each time?

Comment: That will select both `.postid-81` and `.postid-99  .featured-img .caption`, is that what you want? If you want the subselector on both posts, you need to include it on both.

Comment: Please check the edit in the question

Comment: Do you have access to edit the HTML? If so, you could add a single class for the hidden pages. If not, including a rule for each page you want to affect is probably your best option, esspecially if it's only 8 rules.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it like this

```
div[class^="postid-"] .featured-img .caption {
  display:none !important;
}
```

it targets all divs that have a class that starts with "postid-"

Comment: I think the asker is aiming to only hide certain pages, though I may be mistaken.